# How does iOS Multipath Networking works under Developer Mode?

Tags: ios, networking, ios16, multipath, developer-mode

For iOS 16, there are Multipath Networking options in Developer Options menu like these;

- None
- Handover
- Interactive
- Aggregate

I wonder if these options can help with poor home/office wifi connections.
Any ideas how does it work, what are the differences and which option is the most briliant solution that improves responsiveness without draining precious battery juice?

Answer (score 1):

MPTCP works with existing networks. If a network doesn’t support MPTCP, the client uses standard TCP connections. However, network administrators must check their firewall policies to make sure that all intervening devices allow TCP Option 30 to pass through without changes.

Comment: If the wifi network is doing mptcp, you are right, but network is gonna need to have physical multi network paths. But my iPhone already have two network paths. What I wonder is if this setting is about iPhone using it’s wifi and mobile networks simultaneously. Thank you.